# What's an Event Argument?

Tags: formal-semantics

Davidsonian and Neo-davidsonian formal semantics is full of templates containing something labelled as **Event Argument**. For example, In Kratzer (1996, p.1), discussing severing the external argument from its predicate, this sentence is provided:

```
(1) We bought your slippers in Marrakesh.
```

The Davidsonian semantics analyze this sentence as:

```
(1') Ǝe [buy (your slippers) (we) (e) & in(Marrakesh) (e)]
```

Also in Neo-davidsonian semantics, it's taken as:

```
(1'') Ǝe [buying(e) & Agent(we)(e) & Theme(your slippers)(e) & in(Marrakesh)(e)]
```

Why there must be an **Event Argument** realized with **(e)** in both (1') and (1'')? 
Who argued for it in the first place?

Comment: I don't know Davidsonian or Neo-davidsonian theory, but it seems obvious to me that the functions _buy_ and _buying_ need to take an event argument, because each instance of buying is an event which you might need to say something else about, eg where or when it took place.

Comment: Yes, but the 'Where' is already given an argument. It's in Marrakesh with an (e) in both (1') and (1''). But why reduplicating arguments, look at 'Agent', it's already specified as 'we'=argument, but there's an (e) added, again as an argument (event argument), I don't see why.

Comment: But if (e) is not an argument of _buy_, there's nothing to relate the _buy_ to _Marrakesh_. There's an event of buying that happens/ed somwhere, and there is an event that takes place in Marrakesh.

Comment: You mean that in (1''), the set elements are related to each other in terms of 'Arguments', i.e., 'e', 'e', 'e', ...etc. ? If yes, but 'e' has no reality in the EVENT that took place. Agent 'we' does, however. Because it refers to US (Humans) who performed the action. 'e' on the other hand has no reference. I'm really lost :(

Comment: _e_ is a bound variable (as is usual with an existence statement). "There exists an event _e_ such that _e_ is an event of buying (with _we_ as the agent) and _e_ took place in Marrakesh".

Comment: But in Davidsonian & Neo-davidsonian semantics, 'e' is taken as an ARGUMENT not a VARIABLE. 'e' is like the agent, theme, patient, location etc. What I don't understand is why? In the classical logic, there's no such formulas, after Davidson (1967) who took 'it' referring to an event 'Buttering the toast', and since 'it' is an argument, then the event is too. This is the part which is obscure. The logic of 'e' incorporating in the formula is clear, it's more driven by conceptual necessity, but it has nothing to refer to in reality. The event has already been referred to by the verb 'buy'.

Comment: This has got beyond my competence. I know nothing of Davidsonian etc. (I read _Introduction to Monague Semantics_ 30 years ago). I'm just interpreting the formulas you quoted in what seems to me an obvious sense, from my knowledge of mathematics and logic.

Comment: Arguments are generally specified with either variables or constants.

Comment: In a formal system, even "conceptual necessity" must be precisely specified, and that includes repeating indexed arguments for clarity and precision. Even if natural language prefers to delete them viva voce.